# Swedish characters getting converted into unreadable characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, informatica-powercenter

Data is being loaded via informatica from a source into SQL Server 2014 database. The collation of SQL Server is : Latin1_General_CI_AS. It is to be noted that the column is a varchar field, and from the source we are trying to load swedish characters : The word is : ÄLANDS (Note the 2 dots on the A).

After loading it into SQL Server, this is how it looks : ÃLANDS

Instead of loading it into SQL Server i tried loading the same into a flat file, and i can see it is correctly loaded into flat file : ÄLANDS

which makes me conclude that either the collation of SQL Server is incorrect, or there is some other issue. Could someone please assist me, on how i can load the data as it is into SQL Server, so that i can see ÄLANDS, instead of Ã?LANDS?   ALso Add : In informatica the code page is set to : MS Windows Latin 1 (ANSI), superset of Latin1?? Does MS Windows Latin 1 (ANSI), superset of Latin1 support Swedish Characters, the informatica is ASCII repository and not unicode repository.

Comment: can you make the target column an nvarchar instead of varchar?

Comment: `Ä` fits in `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, so collation isn't the issue. The load process itself is, as it either fails to decode your input data correctly, or fails to encode it correctly while sending to SQL Server, with the former being more likely. If I had to speculate, something's going on where the data is converted to/from UTF-8. `Ä` is `0xc3 0x84` in UTF-8, which, when reinterpreted in Windows-1252/`Latin1_General` is `Ã„`. That doesn't explain why the second character would disappear, but it's too close to be a pure coincidence.

Comment: Another (lesser) possibility is that the data is actually correct in SQL Server, but displayed incorrectly by whatever you use to query it. If you're using Management Studio to see "how it looks" that's not an issue, but with other clients and/or third party tools it may be.

Comment: Dear Jeroen, Nice feedback, Let me check the code page at connection level, set in informatica. I think that might be a reason for these kind of issue. I will get back soon. Thanks a lot! But as you mentioned I do see a character 2nd character i dont know how to show it here, is it like a "?" or something, Sorry that i missed it in my question!!!

Comment: Dear snow_FFFFFF, Sure, let me check it and try loading it.

Comment: Dear Jeroen, I have posted a snap in the link : https://imgur.com/a/7TOxUVw  which shows how it looks in SQL Server management studio. Kindly have a look at it, and let me know your thoughts. Meanwhile i am trying out other things.

Comment: Dear snow_FFFFFF, Just tried changing it to nvarchar and reloaded data, doesnt help. :(